# BufferedReader,StreamWriter crash

Tags: java, sockets

Error says the socket is closed... I can send to the server fine, I can recieve from the server fine, but as soon as I try to send and recieve I always get 'Socket is closed' error.

Server:

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(decodedString);
        }
        in.close();

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());           
        osw.write("return: "+decodedString);
        osw.flush();         
        osw.close();
```

Client:

```
    Socket c = new Socket("localhost",4040);    
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream());
    osw.write("Test");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
    String decodedString;
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    } 
    in.close();
    c.close();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Which line of the code you posted throws the `java.net.SocketException`?

Comment: @Ireeder the question is, why does it crash?

Comment: @Mena exception is thrown at the creation of the bufferedreader in client code.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you're closing one of the stream's (`osw.close();`) - the socked gets closed as well.
From `Socket.getOutputStream`'s javadoc:

> Closing the returned {@link java.io.OutputStream OutputStream} will close the associated socket.

Try flushing the streams but close them only when you're done.

Comment: I tried this, but if I don't close the Writer after .write() then the program hangs.

Comment: Try changing `osw.write("Test");` to `osw.write("Test\n");`